# Smalltalks runtime state

Tags: runtime, smalltalk, pharo, conceptual

For Javascript, there exists this excellent intro that explains the runtime state: http://latentflip.com/loupe/

For Smalltalk, I have never found a similar overview of how the runtime and image snapshots are structured.

It is said that a Smalltalk image consists of objects that can send each other messages. This creates many questions:

- Is only one object ever active at a time?
- Is there a "root scheduler" that starts up designated "process" objects?
- Does each suspended image have a list of active objects?
- What happens if two active objects send a message to a third one?
- Can only one message be handled at a time? What is the level of "atomicity"?
- How do two active objects communicate?
- Does every object have an "inbox" of messages received, but not yet processed?
- Does every object have an event loop?

Answer (score 5):

> Is only one object ever active at a time?

Yes, while the systems can schedule different "processes", which are instances of the class `Process` running at different priorities, these take control one at the time. Since the scheduling is non-preemptive, processes must explicitly yield or wait on a semaphore (instance of the class `Semaphore`).

> Is there a "root scheduler" that starts up designated "process" objects?

Yes, the global `Processor` (an instance of `ProcessorScheduler`) keeps and manages the prioritized list of processes that are ready to run (the others being the ones that are waiting on some semaphore).

> Does each suspended image have a list of active objects?

The suspended image is nothing but the image. So, yes, it has everything in it, in particular the `Processor`, which knows who the `activeProcess` is.

> What happens if two active objects send a message to a third one?

Messages are sent one at a time (even though they may be interrupted by the Virtual Machine)

> Can only one message be handled at a time? What is the level of "atomicity"?

The level of atomiciy (non-interruptibility) is essentially the bytecode: message sends, assignments, etc. Any operation perceived as atomic by the programmer.

> How do two active objects communicate?

Objects communicate by means of message sends.

Comment: > Since the scheduling is non-preemptive, processes must explicitly yield or wait on a semaphore
Does this mean that one object entering an infinite loop could stall the entire system?

Comment: No, because the loop can be interrupted at any time. Even an atomic loop like `[true] whileTrue` can be interrupted before "executing" the `true` object. Note however, that your question would deserve a longer explanation.

Comment: I asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258157/smalltalk-can-a-single-object-block-the-entire-system-by-entering-an-infinite-l in the hope that it will receive a longer explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

In some way, the answer to your question depends on the virtual machine that one is using. And while many Smalltalk implementations or derivatives stick pretty close to the original concept, that may vary a lot.

As from your question, it looks like you are interested in conceptual answers, I recommend you to read the original Smalltalk "blue book".

> Smalltalk-80: The Language and Its Implementation. By Adele Goldberg and David Robson, 1983, Addison-Wesley

The book talks in-depth about the design of the system and implementation of the core classes, but also has a few sections, in the end, providing specifications from the VM, interpreter, object memory, etc…